# BlackBox testing/monitoring the Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, black-box-testing

I need to setup some jenkins jobs that probe the cluster every X minutes, and make sure everything is working and functional.  Are there any good off-the-shelf blackbox probers for the Kubernetes API , either opensource or provided by some vendor.

Although I can write my own shell scripts to do test deployments and check things that everything is in good shape , But i am looking for blackbox test suite with some reasonable coverage like:

- checking deployements are working
- replcaSet are doing the replicas
- service discovery and dNS are functional
- configmaps and secrets can be created , and the secret encryption is working
- apiServer latency is not too high
- horizontal pod auto scaling is working
- service can be created and user can connect from outside

Comment: In what way is the existing prometheus machinery insufficient for this task? And, of course, "working and functional" means **a lot** of different things to different people. What risks have you seen that you would like to prevent; because the list isn't "everything that can go wrong," since that's almost infinite.

Comment: promethous does the is white box monitoring

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel there is a need to understand the difference between white box monitoring and blackbox monitoring

Comment: working and functional has only one meaning for a kubernetes component , it doenst have alot of meanings if I say the APIserver is accepting and processing requests  , and the sheduler is schedling the pods , and Service discovery is operational

Comment: Take a look at Heptio Sonobuoy for everything except the last one.